# I've gained slash, but how do I use it?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I've gone and invested 10 skill points in the Swords skill, which unlocked the slash ability:

[image]

This looks like something I would like to do to the various monsters I encounter. How do I activate this ability, or is it simply a sort of passive bonus to my damage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out it is indeed a passive bonus (though for some reason I didn't see it kick in for a while). Every now and then your damage prompt will not only display a number but will also say "Slash". In such cases, you will deal considerably greater damage.

Comment: I'll also point out that it consumes energy, and thus will never happen if your energy bar is empty.